# Rename the `Hilbert` Tag into `Hilbert-Transform`

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There is a tag named [<kbd>hilbert</kbd>](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilbert) which is used mainly in the context of Hilbert Transform.

I suggest renaming it into [<kbd>hilbert-transform</kbd>](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilbert-transform) (Merging it with the current [<kbd>hilbert-transform</kbd>](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilbert-transform) tag).

The Hilbert name is too general and tags better be more specific.

Comment: the tag has been merged. Would you consider marking the question as answered? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree. I've performed this merge and created a synonym so that <kbd>hilbert</kbd> will be matched to <kbd>hilbert-transform</kbd> in the future.

Comment: I think `hilbert` should be removed. It says nothing. Is it Hilbert Space? Is it other things related to Hilbert?

Comment: @Royi That is what will happen when the merge is finished. It takes ~24 hours for all the caches to clear. And it's already redirecting for me.... so I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting? Any usage of `hilbert` will be redirected to the other tag.

Comment: Perfect! Thank You.